# How to build several syntax trees from a sentence?

Tags: python, tree, nlp

I am working on a parser for Russian based on context-free grammar and I would like to build syntax tree for each sentence. It is evidence that for each sentence there can be several trees.

I am not sure about what an efficient way is to build all these trees.

What I have done:

1) after some proccessing I have a sentence where each word has several tags
2) then I build a tree where the leaves are words and then I reduce words to more general phrases (according to grammar); each reduction - new node.
3) when all reductions are done, try to make root with "S -> NP[sbj] VP" rule. It happens only if there is agreement between grammemes.

Result is all trees where root exists.

```py
parser.parse(sent)
[['я', "NP[case='nomn']", ['NPRO', 'sing', '1per', None, 'nomn', None, None]]]

[['хочу', 'V[tran]', ['VERB', 'sing', '1per', None, None, 'tran', 'pres']]]

[['писать', 'VP', ['INFN', None, None, None, None, 'tran', None]], ['писать', 'VP', ['INFN', None, None, None, None, 'intr', None]]]

[['письмо', "NP[case='accs']", ['NOUN', 'sing', None, 'neut', 'accs', None, None]], ['письмо', "NP[case='nomn']", ['NOUN', 'sing', None, 'neut', 'nomn', None, None]]]

[['другу', "NP[case='datv']", ['NOUN', 'sing', None, None, 'datv', None, None]]]

# it is simple example, usually, each word has 3-4 tags.
```

Naive way to do it is just take all possible combinations of words and try to make trees from them. Complexety of this approach is very big. How can I accomplish this task in a more efficient way?

Comment: Neuronal networks to get the tags for each word?

Comment: It works without neuronal networks; it uses dictionary of labelled words.